in non precision approach, why use 2 NM before the final approach fix to start the landing configuration?



i know when vectoring aircraft to the final approach course,controllers are required to ensure the intercept is at least 2 NM outside the approach gate and there is a raim test at 2nm before faf but obvisouly that is not the proper reason.
and for circling approach, i know some company use 2nm before faf to get flap20(boeing) confirguartion to continue the approach(for circling approach fctm and fcom just mention at mda to make landing confirguartion), which one is the right procedure?

some airports faf is just 4nm, eg ymml rnp34, i think it is not suitable to start making landing configuartion at 4+2=6nm, so why boeing use 2nm before faf in sop?



I believe the main reason behind this SOP is to set the DA/MDA and verify modes before the FAF. Re. Allowing for good workload management. I will probably write a longer answer in due course.

As a minor correction, Approach isn't required to get you intercepting the approach course outside 2NM from the gate, that's simply best practice. It's permissible to vector someone closer than that but the maxima are tightened at that point (i.e. the size of the turn to final course goes down from 30 degree maximum to 20 degrees to allow the turn to happen in the shorter distance).  Even vectoring inside the gate is permitted - but the pilot has to specifically request that.  Meteorological minima also apply inside 2NM of the gate.

The approach YMML RNP Rwy 34 has two minima lines and you use the top graphic for the LNAV approach and the second precision approach graphic for the LNVAV/VNAV approach.
These procedures are developed to allow you to slow down and configure without adjusting thrust on the engines.
Let me answer your LNAV question.  You want to be stabilized, fully configured and on speed (VREF) when you decide to descend to the MDA.
For this approach, will will cross AKDEL with flaps 5 and a specific speed.
once you cross AKDEL you are cleared to descend to 1,500 FT MSL at the speed recommended for the airplane you are flying.
If you are at the correct speed and you level off, you will add power necessary to maintain that speed.  At 2NM, you will configure flaps 20 and gear down.  You shouldn't need to touch power as the extra drag will slow you down.  If you planned it correctly, you will be on the correct VREF speed at the FAF where you add full flaps and start to descend.  Again, very little thrust lever movement should occur to stay on VREF while descending down to MDA.
